# how to compare two arrays string

Tags: perl

I have two files as input, a file containing a list of words StopWordsList.txt, I want to remove from StopWordsList.txt the words that are in StopWordsList.txt, here is my code:

```
my $FichierResulat = '/home/lenovo/Bureau/MesTravaux/LeskAlgo/OriginalLeskResult';

open( my $FhResultat, '>:utf8', $FichierResulat );

open( my $fh1, "<:utf8", '/home/lenovo/Bureau/MesTravaux/LeskAlgo/DemoLesk/StopWordsList.txt' ) 
        or die "Failed to open file: $!\n"; #file contains stop words

open( my $fh2, "<:utf8", '/home/lenovo/Bureau/MesTravaux/LeskAlgo/text1.txt' ) #file contains text
        or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";

my @tabStopWords = <$fh1>;

my @tab_contexte;
my @words;

while ( <$fh2> ) {
    chomp;
    next if m/^$/;
    my $context = $_;
    @words = split( / /, $_ );
}
#compare: remove from @words the words existing in @tabStopWords
my %temp;

@temp{@tabStopWords} = 0 .. $#tabStopWords;

for my $val ( @words ) {

    if ( exists $temp{$val} ) {
        print "$val est présent dans tab1 à la position $temp{$val}.\n";
    }
    else {
        print "$val n'est pas dans tab1.\n";
        push @tab_sans_SW, $val;
    }
}

foreach my $value ( @tab_sans_SW ) {
    print $FhResultat "$value\n";
}
```

but in the result file i have all the words existing in @words without removing the word that exist in @tabStopWords..
I hope tha can you help me.

my sotpwords file : 
ال 
الآن 
التي 
الذي 
الذين 
اللاتي 
اللائي 
اللتان 
اللتين

my texte file : 
ومواصلات بما فيه من بريد ونور ومياه وصناعات وعلوم ومعارف وحينما يركب احدنا قطارا فإنه يركب في نفس الوقت على حرية جاهزة اعدها له آلاف العمال والمخترعين والمهندسين في

Comment: What is your question? Do you have a problem? Please indent your code properly so that it is readable.

Comment: i didn't have a true result !!!

Comment: Okay. Please describe the result you get and how it is different from what you want. Thank you for tidying your program.

Comment: what the file1 and file2 contains?

Comment: i'm sorry this is the first time that i publish a question in this forum, so file1 contains Stop words list, file2 is my text, i hope remove from my text (file2) all words existing in file1.. i hope that's clear now

Comment: sample content is main role to understand the process hence could you please try to update the question with similar samples for further understand.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of problems

- You don't `chomp` the contents of `@tabStopWords`, so each entry has a newline at the end
- You overwrite the contents of `@words` each time around the `while` loop with `@words = split(/ /, $_)` instead of adding to it

This program will do what you want. I have added `use autodie` to avoid having to check the result of every `open`, and I have removed a couple of unused variables. Local variable names are better written using just lower-case letters and underscores, especially for readers whose first language isn't English

I've used `split` on both files to reduce them both to individual words. Because `split` also removes newline characters there is no need for `chomp`

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

use constant FICHIER_STOP_WORD => '/home/lenovo/Bureau/MesTravaux/LeskAlgo/DemoLesk/StopWordsList.txt';
use constant FICHIER_TEXTE     => '/home/lenovo/Bureau/MesTravaux/LeskAlgo/text1.txt';
use constant FICHIER_RESULAT   => '/home/lenovo/Bureau/MesTravaux/LeskAlgo/OriginalLeskResult';


my @tab_stop_words = do {
    open my $fh1, "<:utf8", FICHIER_STOP_WORD;
    map { split } <$fh1>;
};

my @words = do {
    open my $fh1, "<:utf8", FICHIER_TEXTE;
    map { split } <$fh1>;
};

my %words = map { $words[$_] => $_ } 0 .. $#words;

open my $fh_resultat, '>:utf8', FICHIER_RESULAT;

for my $word ( @words ) {

    my $position = $words{$word};

    if ( defined $position ) {
        print "$word est présent dans tab1 à la position $position.\n";
    }
    else {
        print "$word n'est pas dans tab1.\n";
        print $fh_resultat "$word\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem would be easier to solve if you showed us the format of your two input files. But as you don't, this will be guesswork.

I guess that your file of stopwords contains a single word on each line. In that case, each element in `@tabStopWords` and, therefore, each key in `%temp` will have newline at the end of them. This makes it extremely unlikely that any of the words in your source file will match these keys.

You probably want to add:

```
chomp @tabStopWords;
```

to your code.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the difference using smart match operator (~~),

```
my(@words_arr) = ("is","a");
my(@input_arr) = ("This","is","a","example","code");
my (@diff)  = grep { not $_ ~~ @words_arr} @input_arr;
```